# Does Atharva Veda 6.8.3 talk about Sun revolving around Earth?

Tags: scripture, vedas, atharva-veda

Griffith translation:

*As in his rapid course the Sun encompasses the heaven and earth,
  So do I compass round thy mind that thou mayst be in love with.
   me, my darling, never to depart.*

Does the first line looks like scientific error?

It says like Sun revolves around the earth.

Comment: I just checked the translation by Indian writer of that verse and it is translated as "Just as Sun fills the Earth and the Sky with lights, in the similar way may I be able to attract your mind, so that may your mind becomes full of desires towards me and you may not go far from me."

Comment: Moving across the sky does not mean revolve...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Atharvaveda 6.8 is called **Kãmãtma Sukta** (or Hymn to fulfill desire). It was heard by sage Jamadagni.

The first line of 6.8.3 is as:

> यथेमे द्यावापृथिवी सद्यः पर्येति सूर्यः ।
>   yatheme dyāvāpṛthivī sadyaḥ paryeti sūryaḥ ।

The meaning is as:

> यथेमे (yatheme) = Just like
>   
>   द्यावापृथिवी (dyāvāpṛthivī) = Earth and Heaven
>   
>   सद्यः (sadyaḥ) = Immediately
>   
>   पर्येति (paryeti) = Reaches
>   
>   सूर्यः (sūryaḥ) = Sun

As the word 'सद्य' / 'Sadya' is used there which means 'Immediately'. So it is referring to the 'Light of Sun'. As it is light of Sun which reaches immediately. So, the meaning is:

> Just as light of Sun reaches immediately Earth and Heaven...

In anycase if one interprets it as 'Sun' only also then it doesn't matter because the verse is nowhere talking about revolution of sun towards earth.

And Vedas do not propagate the idea that rising and setting of sun is due to revolution of Sun towards earth. For eg. RigVeda Aitreya Brahmana 3.44 states:

> एष न कदा चनास्तमेति नोदेति
>   eṣa na kadā canāstameti nodeti
>   
>   *This (Sun) never rises and never sets.*

Comment: @Ajay Sanskrit meaning is not like English sentence where it always follow order of reading. Further it should match as the analogy of next line... also you can check how order isn't related with meaning in verses like here:.. http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga68/ayodhya_68_frame.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is true . I think vedas is corrupted.it would be biggest scientific error .

यथा [Yatha] = As the, Like the.

सूर्य [Surya] = Sun .

एति [Yeti] = goes.

परि [Pari] = around.

घावा [Ghava] = Heaven.

पृथ्वी [Puthvi] = Earth.

[Griffith] Atharva Veda 6.12.1 As the Sun goes round the heaven, have travelled round the Serpents’ race…

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Atharva Veda 6.8.3.:**

> यथेमे द्यावापृथिवी सद्यः पर्येति सूर्यः । एवा पर्येमि ते मनो यथा मां कामिन्यसो यथा मन् नापगा असः ॥३॥

**Hindi Translation by Swami Sri Dayananda Saraswati.:**

> सूर्य जिस प्रकार पृथ्वी आदि लोकों को प्रकाश से संव्याप्त कर लेता है, उसी प्रकार हम अपने प्रभाव से तुम्हारे मन को आकर्षित करते हैं। जिससे तुम हमारे प्रति कामना वाली होकर हमारे पास रहो, दूर न जाओ ॥३॥

> Just as the sun fills the worlds like earth etc with light, in the same way we attract your mind with our influence.  So that you stay with us by loving us, and don't go away from us. ॥3॥

I hope this clarifies your queries.